# Windows 7 on laptop hard drive does not boot after installing Windows to Go on external hard drive

Tags: windows-7, boot, windows-8, usb-storage

Just successfully installed and ran Windows 8's Windows to Go on a USB external hard drive.  However, after shutting down and removing the USB hard disk, whey I to start my laptop (with only Windows 7 installed), but it doesn't boot and trying to repair it doesn't work.

It seems that Windows 8 had corrupted the partition table on the laptop's hard drive, causing Windows 7 to fail to boot.

How do I fix that and avoid future problems of the same type?

Comment: What happens if you plug the USB hard disk in again?

Comment: No problem in usb hard; win 8 boots normally when plugged again; the problem is laptop disk that doen't boot win 7 when removing the usb disk

Comment: this may relate
http://superuser.com/questions/403250/windows-8-to-go-corrupts-host-desktops-drive

Answer (score 1):

To boot Windows Vista, 7, 8 from hard disk you need:

1. Windows MBR on disk
2. Windows NT6 PBR (partition boot record) on active partition
3. \Boot\BCD (boot config data) on active partition with proper loader entries.
4. \bootmgr on active partition

You can use Windows recovery/install DVD/USB, go to repair command prompt:

**bootsect.exe** - to write PBR and MBR

```
bootsect /nt60 all /mbr - should do
```

**bcdboot.exe** - to repair/create BCD (and bootmgr)

```
bcdboot c:\windows - should do (assuming Windows is installed on c:)
```

To set a partition as active you can use **diskpart.exe** (or DiskManagement within Windows).

Windows boot seqeuence from hard disk is always:

1. BIOS loads and executes MBR from first hard disk
2. MBR loads and executes PBR from active partition
3. PBR loads and executes bootmgr from active partition
4. bootmgr reads BCD and displays boot menu (or when only one loader entry in BCD bootmgr loads and executes winload.exe and so on ....)

Comment: thanks for your help ;
I opened command line from windows recovery to find that:
- my windows partition which was assigned the letter 'C:' is healthy but having the last partition letter 'J:'
- the 100MB boot partition (that was not appearing before) is taking the letter 'C:' and all the files you mentioned are existing ;

so, before i try the fix command you mentioned 'bcdboot' , how to fix the unexpected change in partition letters ?

Comment: From Windows 7 DVD, I tried recovery, but got error : volume corrupted..; then tried bcdedit to set device partition from C: to J: but it didn't fix the problem ..; lastly I used diskpart to reassign partition J: letter to C: again and remove the system-reserved boot partition letter, but all that didn't work too !

Answer (score 0):

this is about multi boot with same issue http://www.multibooters.co.uk/articles/drive_letters.html
and this solves a close problem with bcdedit too http://forum.acronis.com/forum/34337

Comment: may be related too http://www.sevenforums.com/installation-setup/190153-windows-partition-changed-itself-d-failing-boot.html

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! While those links may answer the question, it's preferred that you include the essential information in your answer. Link only answers are discouraged here as they're subject to link rot - if the external links become available, the answer is rendered useless.